# TYPO3: tx_news modify news forms

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I'm working on a magazine page. Therefor I would like the client to be able to select the design type when creating/editing a new post. So I'd like to add a custom field to the "edit news", something like a dropdown where all the news (design) types are listed.

For example: News Types:

- Normal
- Interview
- Date
- Special Event

etc...

When the client doesn't select anything it should fallback to a default i.e "Normal" and also it would be nice that when the client selects Interview a second input field shows up where he can enter the persons profession/description.

My goal is, that in the fluid template I can add a line where the selected news type will be added as a class to the list item, something like:

```
<div class="news-item {newsItem.type}"> 
// some code
</div>

will render out as:

<div class="news-item interview">
// some code
<div>
```

I'm not quite sure what I have to add to my custom extension that I'm using to accomplish that.

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to extend the news data with further fields. This is described in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/Index.html) and this [blog](http://www.lukasjakob.com/extend-a-typo3-extbase-model-with-custom-field/)(ext:news is extended, but filestructure is old) and this [article](https://www.sklein-medien.de/en/tutorials/detail/how-to-extend-typo3-database-tables-with-new-fields/)(current fielstructure, but other tabel is enhanced).

For the evaluation and displaying of your fields you need to modify the templates of ext:news. copy the neccessary parts into your extension and provide the modifications to it.
Also set the typoscript to include your templates like described in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/Start/Index.html).

Comment: I've taken a look of this manual aleady, I'm still not sure what I have to modify. In the ext:news I found the tx_news_domain_model_news.php which seemed to include all the property and other stuff, still I don't get how exactly I have to create a new entry

Comment: I aded two further tutorial links

Comment: I'm working on trying those tutorials, now I'm getting confused if I've got my namespace wrong. From the composer.json the name property says "somename/somename-package". Doesn't that mean my namespace should be "namespace Somename\Somename-package\Domain\Model;" keeping the lower/uppercase in mind..

Comment: Through testing I just found out, it was "namespace Somename\SomenamePackage\Domain\Model;" instead of "namespace Somename\Somename-package\Domain\Model;"